# ngx-slick-carousel with clickable image doesn't consistently allow click event

Tags: angular

I am facing a problem using ngx-slick-carousel. I am using a slick carousel with href link.

```
<ngx-slick-carousel class="carousel" 
    #slickModal="slick-carousel" 
    [config]="slideConfig" >

     <div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides | async" class="slide shadow centerImage">
          <a (click)="launchpopup()" href="javascript:void(0);">

          <img src="<<Some link>>">

           </a>
       </div>

</ngx-slick-carousel>
```

1. It loads well.
2. When the carousel starts lets say image 1 on the left slides and
   goes to left which is outside the max slides and so it hides, when
   image 1 comes back on the right side, the click doesn't work  at
   all..only when image 1 goes to its original position it starts to
   work. Same for other images.

Has anyone faced this problem?

Note:- The same problem appears with owl-carousel

Comment: I'ma facing same problem did you manage to find a solution ?

Comment: any solution exist?